# Javascripts no longer working on localhost, production server yes

Tags: javascript, popup, localhost

I have a 2 different javascript events that no longer work on windows7/iis7 localhost, but work on the production server.

One is a shows/hide a div tag, the other is a popup window.

I looked into recent windows update and did not see anything that affected javascript... But perhaps this issue is happening to others as well?!?

Again- both the show and hide div event and the popup window script work on the production server. All browsers javascript fail to work on Localhost.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/shells/javascript/allscripts.cfm"></script>

<!-- The allscripts.cfm file has the following copy....
function showhide(divid, state)
{
document.getElementById(divid).style.display=state
}
-->
</head>

<div id="MarketingDescription-AAA" style="display:block">
    Copy 1<a style="cursor: pointer;" onClick="showhide('MarketingDescription-AAA', 'none'); showhide('MarketingDescription-BBB', 'block'); return true;"><u>[+Expand]</u></a>
</div>

<div id="MarketingDescription-BBB" style="display:none">
    Copy 2<a href="#MarketingDescriptionAnchor" style="cursor: pointer;" onClick="showhide('MarketingDescription-BBB', 'none'); showhide('MarketingDescription-AAA', 'block'); return true;"><u>[--Collapse]</u></a>
</div>
```

Comment: The working of Javascript has NO relation with the server you are using - it depends only on the browser.

Comment: You might want to double-check your server side script...

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: And is there any errors in the browser's console? Are the files actually there on the server?

Comment: @SidharthMudgal, it makes a difference what security sandbox you're in (file:// vs http://), and what directory files are placed in. It's easy to make a mistake with AJAX paths.

Comment: Check the browser dev tools for what's coming back in `/shells/javascript/allscripts.cfm`

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; if you haven't already, please be sure to read the [faq].

Comment: @SidharthMudgal - If it's browser related - I toggle between [link]mywebsite.com (javascript popups & show/hide working) & [link]mywebsite.local (javascripts not working). Code on both sites identical

Comment: @zzzzBov - Good point, the url does not contain file:// - it's http://mywebsite.local (with host script / C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc - pointing to 127.0.1 (working fine))

Comment: Thank you Sidharth Mudgal that fixed it. I'm trying to give you the solved mark but I can not find an easy way to do that...